# javascript touchend if element is over another

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, coordinates, touch-event

Confused on the best method to measure if an element is over another element (visually) during a `touchend` event. Essentially I'm implementing a touch-friendly drag and drop.

I've seen a little bit on `.elementFromPoint()` and `event.touches`, but am unsure how to use these to measure a specific element's bounds. Something like the below.

```
.bind('touchend', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    /* IF (targ is within titles bounds) { append targ to titles} */
    if (titles == document.elementFromPoint(orig.touches[0].pageX,orig.touches[0].pageY)){

        titles.append(targ);
    }

    targ.removeClass('moving').removeAttr('style');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work seamlessly for me, constantly toggle zindex on the dragged element so you can obtain the element below.

```
element.addEventListener('touchmove', touchMove, false);

function touchMove(event) {
    var x = event.targetTouches[0].clientX;
    var y = event.targetTouches[0].clientY;
    dragger.style.zIndex = -1;
    var hoveredElement = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
    console.log(hoveredElement);
    dragger.style.zIndex = options.draggerZIndex;

}
```

If you can ignore old browsers this answer [javascript - elementFromPoint select bottom element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810378/javascript-elementfrompoint-select-bottom-element)
works too just add pointer-events: none