# accessing element hidden behind an IFRAME

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, same-origin-policy

I have a html document which has an iframe on it.some elements of this document are hidden behind this iframe, say a button. I want to find out element of the document at a particular position. For this i have calculated coordinates of the button when there is no iframe on the document. Then i have put iframe again on the document And then i am using document.elementFromPoint() on the previously calculated coordinates.
Here it is giving output as IFRAME on these coordinates. But, I want to know the element behind this iframe. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can try to change z-index of elements behinds the iframe, when you need to find it?

PS: problem like this [javascript - elementFromPoint select bottom element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810378/javascript-elementfrompoint-select-bottom-element)