# JS elementFromPoint get element below retrieved element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a situation in which there are two layers of elements positioned one on top of the other using relative and absolute positioning :

```
<div class="layer1"></div>
<div class="layer2">
   <item />
   <item />
   <item />
</div>
```

I use the top layer (layer 1) to trigger a `mousemove` event, in order to create interaction on the other layers - when the mouse moves over layer1, layer2 is moving accordingly

I need to use `document.elementFromPoint` in order to retrieve an element which is one of the items inside layer2.

But when I do that, the retrieved element is always layer1 - due to the higher `z-index` value it has.

is there a way to make `document.elementFromPoint` ignore layer1? and return layer2 (or items inside layer2) instead?

Thank!

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810378/javascript-elementfrompoint-select-bottom-element), i think you need to lower z-index of up element on mouse move, to get lower element

Comment: @levi, Could you please add JS and CSS too ?

Comment: This is exactly the problem I am facing and Trying to resolve.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your mousemove event to a shim element.