# Get element at point is getting aria-hidden div's instead of the expected element

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I'm using this to get an element from a position

```
private WebElement findElementByPosition(Point position, WebDriver driver) {
  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver ;
  String query = "return document.elementFromPoint(arguments[0], arguments[1])";
  return (WebElement) js.executeScript(query, position.getX(), position.getY());
}
```

So I get the position a known element and I try the method, but I'm getting a hidden div that is over the expected element that has this.

```
<div aria-hidden="true" style="z-index: -1; position: fixed; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px; background-color: transparent; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;"></div>
```

Any ideas on how to avoid this kind of hidden layers when trying to find an element by position?

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8810378/javascript-elementfrompoint-select-bottom-element