# jQuery - Find out which element is directly behind another

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am creating a little box opening game where my users can open a box and an animated spinner scrolls along all of the prizes and lands on their winning prize (indicated by the black line in the middle in the pic below)

[image: Image of the spinner]

After the animation, a whole bunch of box elements that represent the prizes are added to the page. What I am trying to figure out is:

### Using jQuery, how can I find which box the black line lands on?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

**HTML STRUCTURE**

```
<section class="boxes box-background">
    <div class="winning-line" id="line">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="container boxes-container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="open-box">
                        <div id="unbox-area" id="unbox">
                            <div id="cardList">
                               <div class="card" id="prize1">...</div>
                               <div class="card" id="prize2">...</div>
                               <div class="card" id="prize3">...</div>
                               //so on
                            </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </section>
```

**PROBLEM**

Currently, using the code below, I can only get the "open-box" element, not the actual individual "card" class element that the black line landed on.

```
let blackLineEl = document.getElementById("line");  
let rect = blackLineEl.getBoundingClientRect();
let left = rect.x;
let originalDisplay = blackLineEl.style.display;
blackLineEl.style.display = "none"
let winner = document.elementFromPoint(left, 180.0);
blackLineEl.style.display = originalDisplay
console.log(winner.className);
```

I have tried adjusting the static top position to different values, but no luck.

Comment: Use [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) for this. With this you can fire an event when tow elements overlap (intersect).

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`elementFromPoint(x, y)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint)
 method.

> Since document.elementFromPoint returns the topmost element, you'll need to temporarily set your draggable to display:none or pointer-events:none to find elements below it.

Something like:

```
let lineEl = document.getElementById("blackLine")
let x = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(lineEl).left)
let y = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(lineEl).top)
let h = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(lineEl).height)

let originalDisplay = getComputedStyle(lineEl).display
  //hide black line to get element behind it
lineEl.style.display = "none"

let winningBox = document.elementFromPoint(x, y+0.5*h);
lineEl.style.display = originalDisplay

// Do something with winningBox
```

Edit:
You can use [Mike Abdullah's gist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9834895/18762628) that gets all the elements in a given point

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. After using the above code and making a few changes, i have managed to get it to work. The problem is, it will only get the container of the boxes rather than the individual box. I am guessing this is due the the individual boxes being put into the container via Javascript, so this code can't see them?

Comment: Hi, glad it worked. You can upvote then/edit my answer with your modifications. If it get the container share your html and I'll try to help more specifically

Comment: <div class="open-box">
    <div id="unbox-area" id="unbox">
        <div id="cardList">
          //hundreds of individual boxes
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

That's the HTML, current it just gets the "open-box" element

Comment: I'll need more then that. If you are using a computer, you can add code snniped. On your origin question press 'edit', then add code snipped and past your code (or part of it) there and run it.

Comment: In the meanwhile, check this gist that gets all elements in a certain position. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9834895/18762628 then you can itarate them and check for element.classList.contains("open-box") or by id

Comment: Have edited my question, will look at that too

Comment: That was very helpful. I think it didn't work for you because black line top value is higher then box.
Edited asnwer, check out now with 0.5heigth addition

Comment: That returned an empty element. When i set the Y manually, i can get the box-background and open-box classes depending on which Y i use, just can't get anything inside open-box which is strange

Comment: Even when using that GIST and looping through them all, gets everything but stops at open-box element

Comment: Black line y is heiger then the prize box. Add half of the prize box height to getElementByPoint method (see code below, I edited it)

Comment: Yes but i am manually setting the Y so it is within the boxes area

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244370/discussion-between-lior-bakalo-and-ego-gaming).

Comment: One last shot: make sure that prize box style "pointer-events:fill"

Comment: Managed to get it working finally, thanks so much for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: How? What was the problem?